# Sharing a ring buffer between driver and user-space in DriverKit

Tags: macos, driverkit

I'm looking for a fast and efficient way for user-space to send I/O to my driver. One way I'd have hoped to do this, was through a shared memory ring-buffer.

In the [WWDC19 presentation on System Extensions and DriverKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/702/), at roughly 17:00, they mention an IOSharedDataQueueDispatchSource. This doesn't exist in the DriverKit API. An [IODataQueueDispatchSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/iodataqueuedispatchsource) is available, but doesn't seem to be meant to be shared.

In the old IOKit framework, there are similar [IOSharedDataQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/ioshareddataqueue) and [IODataQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/iodataqueue), but they are unavailable in DriverKit.

So, what are my options for implementing a fast, efficient I/O path to my driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that DriverKit does not provide any functionality for this. So I ended up making my own ring-buffer queue.

In essence, I allocate two buffers in my driver -- a submission and a completion queue -- and share these with my user-space application through `CopyClientMemoryForType`. In these buffers I have a head and tail variable and the actual memory for the queue. By atomically advancing head and tail and pushing tasks into the buffer, I can communicate between the two very efficiently. I still do a `IOConnectCallStructMethod` to signal when there's new queue entries.

The code can be found here:

https://github.com/OpenMPDK/MacVFN/blob/90f80296c333e2c2847334c7fd3f8b8b6c8fa656/MacVFN/MacVFN.cpp#L250

https://github.com/OpenMPDK/MacVFN/blob/90f80296c333e2c2847334c7fd3f8b8b6c8fa656/MacVFN/MacVFNUserClient.cpp#L115

https://github.com/OpenMPDK/MacVFN/blob/master/MacVFN/MacVFNShared.h

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful, and seems like a good, relatively simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `IODataQueueDispatchSource` literally says: (emphasis mine)

> A dispatch source that manages a **shared-memory** data queue.

However, the documentation also says the `CopyMemory()` method is private, which would prevent you from sharing the `IOMemoryDescriptor` with a user client.

Fortunately, this isn't actually true in the header file that comes with the DriverKit SDK. In the documentation block it's defined as `private:`, but in the `IODataQueueDispatchSource_Methods` macro, it's in the `public:` block. Go figure.

<s>[Internally, it uses the same `IODataQueueMemory` data structure](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/1031c584a5e37aff177559b9f69dbd3c8c3fd30a/iokit/System/IODataQueueDispatchSourceShared.h#L8) as the kernel's `IOSharedDataQueue`, and the user space [`IODataQueueClient`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOKitUser/blob/main/IODataQueueClient.h).</s> Looks like the layout of the shared-memory `IODataQueueMemory` struct differs from the kernel/user space `IOSharedDataQueue`/`IODataQueueClient`, making it incompatible with those implementations.

Still, it's in principle possible to create the data queue in the dext, grab the memory descriptor with `CopyMemory` when the user client asks to map it, and pass that mapped memory to your app/daemon. The app/daemon will need to implement its own version of the queue logic based on the `IODataQueueDispatchSource` version of `IODataQueueMemory` and `IODataQueueEntry` structs. Far from ideal, but doable.

Comment: Thank you, I also found it quite ambiguous. Sadly, the two definitions for `IODataQueueMemory` seem to be incompatible? The one `IODataQueueClient` uses has a `queueSize` as first member https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/1031c584a5e37aff177559b9f69dbd3c8c3fd30a/iokit/IOKit/IODataQueueShared.h#L57

Comment: @MadsY Ugh, you're right. Worse, they've added `needServicedCallback` and `_resv` fields in the `IODataQueueDispatchSource` version of `IODataQueueMemory`, which prevents you from hacking it up to be compatible. So yes, you can use this on the DriverKit end, but you'll need to implement (or adapt) your own user space end of the queue. Well done Apple. Seems worth reporting to them as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'll go and report this to Apple, and try to adapt something myself. I'll come back and post the answer if it works out.

Comment: @MadsY: Would love to hear if you got something working here.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen I've got some upcoming changes on a dext where I'm hoping to switch to this technique. I'll make sure to open-source my solution (and will add a link here).

Comment: @AndrewMadsen I've been working on it a little this week, but nothing functional yet. Maybe my solution is going to be a little too domain-specific, but I promise to share it here once it's ready.
Also my report to Apple is getting stonewalled, so I don't expect anything from that side soon.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen My implementation is now available. Again, it's quite specific to NVMe, but still should be a valid example for others https://github.com/OpenMPDK/MacVFN/